# Inserting an image into Bootstrap according is breaking collapse function

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, accordion

I am attempting to insert an image into a bootstrap accordion and when I do it makes that section (second accordian section) of the accordion remain open - where it should be collapsed initially allowing for someone to click on it to expand it.

Not sure what it is breaking in the code that is causing this. 
Here is a link to code in JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/penrysh/1fLfx04m/3/#&togetherjs=dJTKolqwum

```
<p><strong>Complete the sections below to upload content.</strong></p>
<div class="container" style="width: 90%;">
<div id="accordionCO0137098" class="panel-group" style="width: 90%;">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapseCO0137098_0" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionCO0137098">Access System</a></h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseCO0137098_0" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body"><ol>
<li>Click the <strong>User Name </strong>field</li>
<li>Type your ID</li>
<li>Click the <strong>Password </strong>field</li>
<li>Type your password</li>
<li>Click the <strong>Log In </strong>button</li>
</ol></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapseCO0137098_1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionCO0137098">Add a New Content</a></h4>
</div>
<div class="panel-body"><ol>
<li>Click the <strong>Content </strong>tab at the top left of the screen<br /><a class="largeimage img-view" href="images/content.png" target="_blank"><img style="width: 248px; height: 71px;" src="images/content.png" alt="" width="225" height="56" border="0" /></a></li>
<li></li>
</ol></div>
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapseCO0137098_2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionCO0137098">Complete the Required Fields</a></h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseCO0137098_2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">
<p>Note: You may type a note here.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapseCO0137098_3" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionCO0137098">Upload the Content</a></h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseCO0137098_3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">
<p>Note: You may type a note here.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapseCO0137098_4" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionCO0137098">Tag the Content</a></h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseCO0137098_4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">
<p>Note: You may type a note here.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapseCO0137098_5" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionCO0137098">Add Any Relevant Keywords</a></h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseCO0137098_5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">
<p>Note: You may type a note here.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapseCO0137098_6" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionCO0137098">Add Folders</a></h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseCO0137098_6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">
<p>Note: You may type a note here.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapseCO0137098_7" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionCO0137098">Add Any Relevant Search</a></h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseCO0137098_7" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">
<p>Note: You may type a note here.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapseCO0137098_8" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionCO0137098">Add Any Relevant Related Content</a></h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseCO0137098_8" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">
<p>Note: You may type a note here.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapseCO0137098_9" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionCO0137098">Send For Review</a></h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseCO0137098_9" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">
<p>Note: You may type a note here.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You messed up the libraries.

Moreover, after the "panel-tile" ... "Add a New Content Object" it's required the

```
<div id="collapseCO0137098_1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

And, before the

```
 `<div class="panel-heading">`
```

it's required the

`<div class="panel panel-default">`

The new jsFiddle is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1fLfx04m/9/).

The snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<p><strong>Complete the sections below to upload content in the LT&amp;I CMS.</strong></p>

<div class="container" style="width: 90%;">
    <div id="accordionCO0137098" class="panel-group" style="width: 90%;">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapseCO0137098_0" data-toggle="collapse"
                                           data-parent="#accordionCO0137098">Access the CMS</a></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseCO0137098_0" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ol>
                        <li><a href="https://klcm.antheminc.com/aries/index.cfm?" target="_blank">Click this link to
                            access: https://klcm.antheminc.com/aries/index.cfm?</a></li>
                        <li>Click the <strong>User Name </strong>field</li>
                        <li>Type your US Domain ID</li>
                        <li>Click the <strong>Password </strong>field</li>
                        <li>Type your US Domain password</li>
                        <li>Click the <strong>Log In </strong>button</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--  FIX: next line missing  -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapseCO0137098_1" data-toggle="collapse"
                                           data-parent="#accordionCO0137098">Add a New Content Object</a></h4>
            </div>
            <!--  FIX: next line missing  -->
            <div id="collapseCO0137098_1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ol>
                        <li>Click the <strong>Content </strong>tab at the top left of the screen<br/><a
                                class="largeimage img-view" href="images/content.png" target="_blank"><img
                                style="width: 248px; height: 71px;" src="images/content.png" alt="" width="225"
                                height="56"
                                border="0"/></a></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapseCO0137098_2" data-toggle="collapse"
                                           data-parent="#accordionCO0137098">Complete the Required Fields On the
                    Properties
                    Panel</a></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseCO0137098_2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Note: You may type a note here.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapseCO0137098_3" data-toggle="collapse"
                                       data-parent="#accordionCO0137098">Upload the Content on the Content Panel</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseCO0137098_3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Note: You may type a note here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapseCO0137098_4" data-toggle="collapse"
                                       data-parent="#accordionCO0137098">Tag the Content Items With All Applicable
                Categories</a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseCO0137098_4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Note: You may type a note here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapseCO0137098_5" data-toggle="collapse"
                                       data-parent="#accordionCO0137098">Add Any Relevant Keywords</a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseCO0137098_5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Note: You may type a note here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapseCO0137098_6" data-toggle="collapse"
                                       data-parent="#accordionCO0137098">Add Folders to Content Item</a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseCO0137098_6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Note: You may type a note here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapseCO0137098_7" data-toggle="collapse"
                                       data-parent="#accordionCO0137098">Add Any Relevant Search Collections</a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseCO0137098_7" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Note: You may type a note here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapseCO0137098_8" data-toggle="collapse"
                                       data-parent="#accordionCO0137098">Add Any Relevant Related Content</a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseCO0137098_8" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Note: You may type a note here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#collapseCO0137098_9" data-toggle="collapse"
                                       data-parent="#accordionCO0137098">Send For Review</a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseCO0137098_9" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Note: You may type a note here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```